# Multiple apache processes  with over 33% cpu and 1.3g memory each?

Tags: apache, memory, memory-leaks, process

we have a number of sites hosted on an Amazon x-large AWS server. When ever i restart apache, i'll run **top** and see number of apache processes (6-8) that will quickly ramp up cpu percentage and memory percentage up to 33% cpu, sometimes 50% cpu and up to 1.3g of memory each! they will stay in **top** for 10 - 20 min, then another will start up with the same behavior.

if i do an **strace** on one of these processes i'll get an edless list like this below:

```
access("/etc/localtime", R_OK)          = 0

access("/etc/localtime", R_OK)          = 0

access("/etc/localtime", R_OK)          = 0

access("/etc/localtime", R_OK)          = 0

access("/etc/localtime", R_OK)          = 0
...
```

the list will not stop. if i leave these processes going, they will eventually stall the server and i need to reboot the entire virtual machine.

anyone have any ideas on why the process keeps accessing this file, or another approach to how i can find out why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried removing the sites that are hosted there and adding them one-by-one until you get this behavior? It's likely a bug in one of the sites.

Comment: that's an interesting approach, but unfortunately i cannot take the sites down for any amount of time. do you think there is a way i can track which webpage/file is responsible?

Comment: Yes...take each site down to see if it fixes it. If people complain, say it's a security thing. Since you are already restarting Apache, you are already taking them down for at least a little bit.

Comment: whe i restart apache the downtime is so fast that no one notices. That's why i can get away with it. But if this is the only approach then so-be-it, i'll wait later in the day and try it then. Thanks.

Comment: I'd check `lsof` for clues. It may show an open file (e.g., someone's broken PHP script). `gdb` is another approach. You can bring them down in far less than 10–20 min, BTW, using a SIGKILL (kill -9). Also, check `mod_status` with `ExtendedStatus` on.

Comment: @derobert mod_status was key! I activated that module and used it accordingly, and it showed exactly what url was at issue, which happened to be the same url for each process. Was a 2 line code fix. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I guess I'll post that as an answer then :-P

Answer (score 2):

If you enable `mod_status` and set `ExtendedStatus on`, then you can visit `http://server/server-status` (or other location you set to use the `server-status` handler) and you'll get a table of what each Apache process/thread is doing:

> ```
> Srv  PID   Acc        M  CPU   SS  Req   Conn  Child  Slot  Client  VHost            Request
> ⋮
> 3-0  2129  0/167/167  _  1.13  495 0     0.0   0.33   0.33  ::1     Zia.metrics.net  GET /mrtg/mrtg-l.png HTTP/1.1
> 4-0  2130  1/150/150  W  1.11  0   0     1.4   0.30   0.30  ::1     Zia.metrics.net  GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
> ⋮
> ```

The status page include a full key and field description, as well as some other summary status. You should probably protect it to only be visible to you, not the Internet:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
</Location>
ExtendedStatus On
```

You can use any access control method available in Apache (e.g., Basic or Digest authentication), of course.